# Has anyone list of stackoverflow team members blogs?

Tags: discussion

Wasn't sure if my question belongs here, but I'm following currently
https://blog.stackoverflow.com and http://www.codinghorror.com (I know he's not anymore in stackoverflow), and I saw couple videos on tekpub from current/past stackoverflow team members   and those were quite interesting, so I'm wondering if there any blogs from stackoverflow team, that must be followed.

Comment: Look at the profiles of the team. Some of them post links to blogs or other areas they contribute.

Answer (score 5):

The [Stack Exchange Management Team](https://stackexchange.com/about/management) consists of the CEO, CFO, VP of Products, and the Board of Directors, and they are all notable people worth following. There may be links to other areas they contribute to. If not, you can Google their names and see what comes up.

It's worth noting that Joel Spolsky runs [Joel On Software](http://joelonsoftware.com/), a popular blog on software development, which is read by developers all over the world.

As for the [Stack Exchange Team](https://stackexchange.com/about/team), the team page may link to Stack Exchange profiles, which may of course link to personal blogs, Twitter accounts, LinkedIn profiles, and other sites they contribute to during their personal time. The same rule applies here as it does with the management team: If you don't see information in their profile, try Googling them and see what comes up.

Lastly, the Stack Exchange System Administrators run the [Server Fault Blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/).